# partial integration of specific formula

Tags: integration

Consider following equation:

$\int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta s}\alpha(s)ds=\dfrac{1}{\theta}[e^{\theta s}\alpha(t)-\alpha(0)]+\dfrac{1}{\theta}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\theta s}\dot \alpha(s)ds$

Is this equation valid because of partial integration?

Comment: Can $\theta$ be zero?  Is $\alpha$ differentiable?

Comment: @Eric Towers $\theta$ is postive, $\alpha$ is differentiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of *Integration By Parts*:

\begin{align}
\int^t_0 e^{\theta s}\alpha(s) ds &= \frac{1}{\theta}\left[e^{\theta s}\alpha(s)\right]^t_{0} - \frac{1}{\theta}\int^t_0 e^{\theta s}\dot{\alpha}(s) ds
\end{align}

Comment: where is $\dot \alpha(s)$?

Comment: Edited to include $\dot{\alpha}$

Comment: but in my formula there is plus not minus

Comment: Oh I see, is this a solution you are trying to attain from e.g. a textbook?

Comment: its from a paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229025741_The_Pontryagin_maximum_principle_for_infinite-horizon_optimal_controls page 26

Comment: What page exactly (just to save me time from searching for it)

Comment: its on page 26 in the middle. the following proof would not work with a "minus".

Comment: Thank you Naji. It was a mistype in the original document. Unfortunatly i had to adjust my proof, but it worked out.